# SCSS @media compile error

Tags: css, compiler-errors, sass, prepros

I'm using Prepros to compile my SCSS files to CSS, but it gives me an error when i try to use media queries. I tried Coala and Scout as well.
If i just copy this code into output CSS it works.
What am i doing wrong?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  body {
    width: 320px;
  }
  .wrapper {
    width: 320px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .works-wrap {
    width: 320px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 610px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 320px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .works-wrap {
    width: 320px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 610px) and (max-width: 950px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 650px;
    margin: 4% auto;
  }
  .name {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .works-wrap {
    width: 650px;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
}​

@media only screen and (min-width: 950px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 950px;
    margin: 4% auto;
  }
  .name {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .works-wrap {
    width: 950px;
  }
}
```

Error code:

```
Error: Invalid CSS after "​": expected selector, was "@media only scr..."
        on line 169 of style.scss

164:     width: 650px;
165:     margin-left: 10px;
166:   }
167: }​
168: 
169: @media only screen and (min-width: 950px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
170:   .wrapper {
171:     width: 950px;
172:     margin: 4% auto;
173:   }
174:   .name {

Backtrace:
style.scss:169
c:/Program Files (x86)/Prepros/resources/app/ruby/ruby_gems/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1165:in `expected'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it is a copy/paste mistake

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    body {
        width: 320px;
    }
    .wrapper {
        width: 320px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .works-wrap {
        width: 320px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 610px) {
    .wrapper {
        width: 320px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .works-wrap {
        width: 320px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 610px) and (max-width: 950px) {
    .wrapper {
        width: 650px;
        margin: 4% auto;
    }
    .name {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .works-wrap {
        width: 650px;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 950px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .wrapper {
        width: 950px;
        margin: 4% auto;
    }
    .name {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .works-wrap {
        width: 950px;
    }
}
```

There is a **hidden char** just after the **closing bracket** of `@media only screen and (min-width: 610px) and (max-width: 950px)` just delete it

Comment: Thank you! That helps, how can i find it by myself?